# How to create dynamic 'types' in database

Tags: mysql, database, database-design

My question relates to a php website with a mysql database.

Currently in the database we have a 'token' entity

a token can hold 0 or more 'object' entities and each of these objects can be of type x, y, z

so

```
----------
| Token  |
|--------|

--------------
|token_object|
|            |
|tokenID     |
|objectID    |
--------------

------------
| object   |
|          |
|objectType|
------------

------------  --------- ---------
| objectX  |  |objectY| |objectZ|
|          |  |       | |       |
------------  --------- ---------
```

Now this works okish, because when I want the data from an object which, due to the nature of our caching system, is almost always one object at the time I can just make two queries to get the data from object and objectX/Y/Z

```
(SELECT * FROM object WHERE id = $id)
```

and

```
switch($objectType)
case 'objectX':
    SELECT * from ObjectX WHERE id = $id
case 'objectY':
etc etc..
```

But now I've been asked to allow users of the website to create new object types, ie objectA/B etc.

I could just create a new objectXn table for each new object type, and by choosing a good value for objectType that would work

```
(SELECT * FROM $objectType WHERE blabla)
```

but that doesn't seem to be a very clean solution, especially the creation of new tables

Are there any better solutions?

Worth noting is that I expect that there are a lot of objects relative to tokens and that the creation of extra object types won't happen a lot/almost never

Comment: I'm removing the PHP tag from this. Although you implement your solution in PHP, the heart of the question is in reference to MySQL and, as such, the PHP doesn't belong .

Comment: Do the object tables all have the same fields? Er wait, no, I think I see -- object has the fields common to all objects and objectX has the fields unique to X?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What exactly are you storing? Does it need complex queries against it or do you need a simple object-storage by id? In the latter case, you can create a table that has an ID, Type and Data, where data is the serialized object that you can restore in your code (for example, storing your object as JSON, and de-serializing it with the stored Type and the Data). A little more context in your question is appreciated if this doesn't satisfy your needs.

Comment: I would need to run queries on the data in the object types, for instance if an ObjectZZ was added, which fields: price and currency. And I wanted all tokens which had the currency EURO

Comment: This kind of context requires you to create tables for each type of object to allow querying against a particular property of that object. This is due to the nature of a relational database, it cannot create columns on the fly. Depending on your total overall situation, you might be better of with a NoSQL solution (such as MongoDB) since this is a document storage that does allow you to query on fields on dynamically created objects, with zero performance impact.